# Excel VBA to search a name in a range and update the value of adjacent cell

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an Excel VBA in which so far I have created macros which update a line graph one value at a time. In this graph I am showing Rank as a label. I am stuck: in highlighting the label when there is a change in the Rank.

As you can see in the image, each point in the graph is plotted using the macro.
For each legend entry whenever the rank changes, the macro should highlight the data label in the graph

[image: Screenshot of the graph I created so far]

Comment: welcome to Stack Overflow! please post the code you've tried so far and any attempts you've already had at solving the problem.

Comment: Hi @SpencerBarnes Here is the code I took from web:
Column A has ranks of suppliers in column B, and the macro inserts the latest rank of the supplier in E2 & F2. If the rank changes, then it should inert "Yes / No" in E3 and F3
Sub U ()
For i = 1 To 10
For Each cell In ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 2)
      If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Tester" Then
      ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 5).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If    
   If ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = "Tested" Then
      ActiveSheet.Cells(2, 6).Value = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value
    End If    
Next
Next i
End Sub

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to clarify the question a little more - as far as I can tell, that code would do the following: run through rows 1 to 10 of the active sheet, and for the lowest/last rows with 'Tester' or 'tested' it found in column B, update Cells E2 and F2 respectively with those rows' values from column A. Which part of that isn't how you'd want it?

Comment: While I'm thinking about it, for best practice you should consider using a [With Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement) on `Activesheet` or your sheet object to make the code less wordy

Comment: Also, the inner `For` loop there isn't doing anything at all - `For each cell in` and then a single cell reference? I guess that's the bit that isn't working how you'd expect it? If it isn't then you can cut it out without affecting your code at all.